# Android Dagger how to perform DI in View components

Tags: android, view, dependency-injection, dagger

I am using Dagger and so far its good. I have one module for all the Views (Activities and fragments), and I am injecting them through Object graph. Now I want to include Custom view and my Module looks something like this

```
@Module(
injects = {
    //Activity
    MainActivity.class,


    //Fragments
    LookupSearchResultsFragment.class,


    // Views

    MainSearchComponent.class
},
//includes = {
//    PersistenceModule.class
//},
library = true,
complete = false,
addsTo = AndroidModule.class)
```

In my MainSearchComponent how should I inject Object Graph? I am currently doing this:

```
ObjectGraph.create((BaseActivity)getContext()).inject(this);
```

But I get this error. `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class ...MainActivity could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should pass `@Module`-annotated classes to `ObjectGraph.create()`, not `Activity` classes. Secondly, you should not create graph every single time you need to `inject()` something. 
The common practice is to make `objectGraph` a field of your `Application` class. That's what you can get:

```
// Application class
objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new AndroidModule());
```

Then in your `Activity`'s `onCreate()`:

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  MyApp app = (MyApp) getApplication();
  activityGraph = app.getObjectGraph().plus(new ActivityModule());
  activityGraph.inject(this); // inject with respect of activity-specific components
}
```

And don't forget to clear strong ref to local graph to GC it ASAP:

```
@Override public void onDestroy() {
  activityGraph = null;
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: what if I want to inject a class with run time variables? It wont help me to inject everything in Application class then would it?

Comment: @SoH What do you mean by runtime vars? Can you give an example?

Comment: I have class A which injects another class B based on the variables it receives from the calling class C. Is it doable?

Comment: @SoH you can implement `@Provides B provideB(C c)` and `@Provides C provideC()` methods in one of your modules. Then based on the `C` value provided into first method by the second method, you can decide what particular `B` instance to provide. Of course, in `A` you will mark `B` instance with `@Inject`. Is it what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

ok so I found the solution. I needed to inject the module where I have specified my component. So for me I had to write the following instead of

```
ObjectGraph.create((BaseActivity)getContext()).inject(this);
```

This got it working.

```
ObjectGraph.create(new AcitivityModule()).inject(this);
```